# AJAX toolkit Accordion doesn't work when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using an AJAX accordion from the AJAX control toolkit to display a dynamic list of items, which are pulled from a database. I generate the entire accordion from code behind. This works without problems when testing it locally, but when i publish it online, the accordion shows the first item but doesn't do anything else when clicked, basically not responding to anything. There are also links to other pages inside the accordionpane contents, and these do work.

For aspx i'm using a masterpage with inside it a toolkitscriptmanager:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

and in the content i also added a scriptmanagerproxy in the hopes that that would solve the problem, but it didn't.

the empty accordion is like this:

```
<asp:accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server"
HeaderCssClass="Header" ContentCssClass="Contents"
Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10"
BorderColor="#000000" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1"
FramesPerSecond="100" FadeTransitions="true"
TransitionDuration="500">
</asp:accordion>
```

This is my current code to generate the accordion:

```
public void getRequests()
    {

        DataTable requests = getRequests();

        if (requests.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < requests.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            DataTable makers = getInformationByRequest();
            AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane pane1 = new AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane();
            pane1.ID = "pane" + i;
            Table table = new Table();
            table.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.CssClass = "Header";
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Create panel head with information
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            pane1.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(table);

            Table table1 = new Table();
            table1.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

            TableRow rowhead = new TableRow();
            rowhead.CssClass = "Contents";

            TableCell cellName = new TableCell();
            cellName.Text = "Bedrijf naam";
            TableCell cellStatus = new TableCell();
            cellStatus.Text = "Request status";
            TableCell cellAction = new TableCell();
            cellAction.Text = "Actie";

            rowhead.Cells.Add(cellName);
            rowhead.Cells.Add(cellStatus);
            rowhead.Cells.Add(cellAction);

            table1.Rows.Add(rowhead);

            for (int j = 0; j < makers.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                TableRow row1 = new TableRow();

                if (makers.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    //method to create table1
            }
            pane1.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(table1);
            }

            Accordion1.Panes.Add(pane1);
        }
```

This works without any problems when debugging, as i've said.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I solved it by using this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2007/03/28/110161.aspx

Thanks to henk mollema for putting me on the right track.

Comment: nope, not at all, it is simply not responding.

Comment: Does AjaxControlToolkit require any DLL assemblies? If so, you need  to publish them too.

Comment: Yes, it does. The DLL is inside my bin folder in the published project though. Shouldn't this make it work?